# How to restore previous pae

Tags: pae

I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS on VMWare Workstation. On server, I installed `Ubuntu-desktop`. Everything is OK. But when I upgraded `pae` and other files pointed by update manager, It became trouble. Desktop size become shrink and cannot scroll down or right and left enough. What's wrong? I want my original version.
[image] How to do? Answer me please.

Comment: can you provide some `screenshots`

Comment: @SauravKumar I edited my post and I added one screenshot.

Comment: Try it once.. In `dash` search `System Settings` and open it. Click on the `Displays` icon and try to change `Resolution`. Hope it would help.. Reply what happens..

Comment: @SauravKumar thz for your reply. I tried it. But there are also other problems. When I pointed dash home with my mouse, there is no effect. I meant is when i point dash home, the effected icon is Home folder.EFFECTED ICON AND REAL POINTING ARE MISS MATCHED !!! Finally i can open System settings but system setting is opened in the middle of the screen where I cannot reach (because there is no scroll). You can see in my picture, I opened Mysql query browser, but can't access because query browser is opened in the middle of the screen where i can't access. pls help me.

Comment: ok.. open terminal(ctrl+alt+t) run this command.. `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1366x768` Although you are not able to see terminal just type this be sure you are not doing any mistake.. Here `1366x768` is resolution you want to set. I recommend you to set the same resolution you are currently using for `Windows`

Comment: My windows 7's recommeded screen resolution is 1280x800 and it is the highest. Can I change?

Comment: Then use `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x800` first.. If it fails then try `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1366x768` it it also fails then try some other low resolution like `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768`

Comment: I run root@ubuntuntwo~# xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x800. And the err is " xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default. warning: output VGA1 not found; ignoring"

Comment: If you are not able to see what the display shows then it is fairly impossible to fix your problem.. Uff!! Okay! Follow my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the you are following these steps very precisely without `clicking or highlighting` other window.. So I recommend you don't click some other place while following these steps..

- Open `System Settings` from *Dash* (as you told that you already opened but it was not visible, so don't worry, without seeing it you can change..)
- Without cling some other place type displays and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- again without clicking any other press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- then press <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow key once
- then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> two times then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again two times..

Try it it will change your resolution!! Reply for further assistance!!

Comment: I 've tried Saurav. I've tried many times. After restarting, the display is same as before. No change. :(

Comment: Okay! Last option.. repeat above step and press alt+a key once. If still not working.. Then try to these option: `VGA` , `LVDS` ,`DP1` , `TV` , `TMDS-1` , `TMDS-2` , `LVDS1` , `DVI1` ,`VGA-0` , `S-video` , `DVI-0` in place of `VGA1` in this command: `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1366x768`. If still doesn't work then I would recommend you to use `Windows + Ubuntu Dual Boot`

Comment: Thz for ur patient help. I have done all the best. but doesn't change. Now I found that this is because new pae download "linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic-pae". My old pae version is 3.2.0-29-generic-pae. So I tried while first starting, I click shift and enter into bootloader menu. I chose "previous version" tap. and I choose my old 3.2.0-29. Finally, I can restore my previous state. Why do this become fine? I don't know reason. And friend, how to change 3.2.0-29 to be my default pae?